# HTML Form Select and Arrays, PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a form with multiple rows and multiple "select" drop-down menus in each row. For simplicity I am showing 2x2 in this example but in reality it could go up to 5x5.

In simplified form, my HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="aaa2.php" method="post" name="book">

<?php $roomNumber=101; ?> 
Normal Occupancy 
<select name="occupancy[101]"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
Extra Beds
<select name="extrabed[101]"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<?php $roomNumber=101; ?>
Normal Occupancy 
<select name="occupancy[102]"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
Extra Beds
<select name="extrabed[102]"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

On the next page, I can easily display the information from the first drop-down:

```
<?php 
$occupancy_array=$_POST['occupancy'];
foreach($occupancy_array as $roomNumber=>$occupancy) {
echo "Room ".$roomNumber.". Normal occupancy is ".$occupancy.".<br>";   
}
?>
```

My problem comes when I try to use the information from the second drop-down. I've got this far

```
<?php 
$occupancy_array=$_POST['occupancy'];
$extrabed_array=$_POST['extrabed'];
foreach($occupancy_array as $roomNumber=>$occupancy) {
echo "Room ".$roomNumber.". Normal occupancy is ".$occupancy." and the room will take ".$extrabed." extra beds.<br>";   
}
?>
```

but obviously I need another foreach line for the second array. I've tried it in series and I've tried it nested inside the first foreach, but neither works right. Is there a way that I can combine it all into one foreach? Or how should I do it?

Comment: You mean combine `occupancy` and `extrabed` together?

Comment: Yes. I need to be able to construct the next page with occupancy and extra bed information for each roomNumber.

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't want to have two `foreach`s?

Comment: I think I got your point. You can use `$roomNumber` to access extra beds. Something like `$extrabed_array[$roomNumber]` in your `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$occupancy_array=$_POST['occupancy'];
$extrabed_array=$_POST['extrabed'];

foreach($occupancy_array as $roomNumber => $occupancy) {
    echo "Room $roomNumber. Normal occupancy is $occupancy and the room will take ".$extrabed_array[$roomNumber]." extra beds.<br>";   
}
```

You should take care to injections, because any user can send a request with

```
occupancy[<script>...</script>] = <script>...</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Recode. That worked perfectly. Now I'm going to charge on putting that logic into the real thing.

I take your point about injections, but this was just a very simple example to address my problem. I cut out all the superfluous stuff.

Comment: @TrapezeArtist yes, it was just a notice, there are enough people forgetting that.